# Where can I ask a question about my Motorola phone not finding Wi-Fi?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask the following question?

> My Motorola phone will not find our WiFi but will find my neighbor's. Note, my laptop can connect perfectly to my WiFi. My Motorola is an Android-based phone.
>
> I've tried turning my phone and modem on then off again. I've reset my WiFi settings and forgotten all my saved WiFi's. I've called Motorola and my broadband service provider, and no help was received. I've tried everything.

Sorry if the tags are misleading in anyway, and I have no idea where to ask this question. If you can direct me, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about the "off-topic" mark. Please note that as we get a lot of blatantly off-topic posts on this site, people are quick to close them, so we expect site recommendation questions to be explicitly phrased as such. I've edited your question with the expected format; the mark should be removed soon.

Answer (score 3):

It's an Android phone, so that's a question for [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/):

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> **Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange** is for users of the Android operating system.
>
> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device
>
> then this is the right place to ask.

(from their [Help Center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))